Problema sumatoria en función de python
Por recomendación de los compañeros, voy a volver a escribir la pregunta, explayando más en el problema.Este código es parte de un programa de control de pesajes. Hay mucho código referente a la maquetación de la interfaz gráfica que estoy dejando por fuera, pero lo que pasa en esencia es lo siguiente:
Hay un ciclo while que está siempre recibiendo la señal del indicador y repitiéndola en un canvas. Dentro de ese ciclo while hay un condicional que, si es verdadero, ejecuta la función pedido.pesar_ingrediente() hasta que la receta del diccionario se termine.
Lo que debiera de pasar es que el trabajador abra el módulo en su computadora, seleccione la receta y se ejecute la clase pedido, luego, pesa uno por uno los ingredientes, cada vez que le indique que ha llegado al peso deseado de un ingrediente, la receta se actualiza y le indica el pesaje del siguiente hasta que acabe. Por tanto, el usuario usa la computadora lo menos posible
He reescrito mi código, siguiendo el ejemplo de la respuesta, pero sigue dándome problemas sumando mal el acumulado después de que termino de pesar el primer ingrediente. Voy a dejar el código que tengo para que intenten reproducirlo, pero sé que es muy complicado, pues si bien en este ejemplo, uno le dice al programa cuanto está marcando la balanza, no es el caso en la práctica, porque el indicado siempre está mandando un peso.
Primero les dejo la clase, tal cómo está en el código principal:
class Pedido:
    margen_de_error = 0.05

    def __init__(self, peso_receta):
        self.peso_acumulado = 0
        self.peso_receta = peso_receta

    def definir_peso_ingrediente(self, peso_ingrediente):
        #Aquí sumamos la cantidad de ingrediente que dice la receta más el peso acumulado de la balanza 
        # (pues al pesar los otros ingredientes, hay que tener en cuenta ese peso)
        self.peso_ingrediente=self.peso_acumulado+peso_ingrediente
        return round(float(self.peso_ingrediente), 3)
    
    def pesar_ingrediente(self, peso_balanza, ingrediente):
        #Esta es la parte en la que estoy trabajando, 
        #hay un error cuando se llama la función Pedido.peso_ingrediente
        if abs(self.definir_peso_ingrediente(ingrediente)-peso_balanza) <= Pedido.margen_de_error:
            print('peso correcto')
            restar_ingrediente()
            self.alcualizar_primer_ingrediente(receta)
            self.actualizar_peso_acumulado(peso_balanza)

            
        else:
            print('peso incorrecto')

    def alcualizar_primer_ingrediente(self, receta):
        try:
            primera_llave=list(receta.keys())[0]
        except:
            return
        peso_ingrediente=receta[primera_llave]
        return round(float(peso_ingrediente), 3)

    def actualizar_peso_acumulado(self, peso):
        self.peso_acumulado=round(float(peso), 3)
    
    def peso_completo(self):
        #Esta parte todavía no la estoy usando, pero cuando arregle lo anterior, 
        #me va a servir para indicar que el pesaje de la receta está completo
        return abs(self.peso_receta - self.peso_acumulado)  <= Pedido.margen_de_error;

Ahora dejo las funciones externas que trabajan con el diccionario de la receta:
#Receta
receta={'maiz':2.0, 'proteinas':0.2, 'vacuna':0.2, 'hierro': 0.1}
def sumar_peso_receta(receta):
    peso=0.00
    for i in receta.keys():
        peso+=receta[i]
    print(round(float(peso), 3))
    return round(float(peso), 3)
sumar_peso_receta(receta)

def restar_ingrediente():
    primera_llave=list(receta.keys())[0]
    receta.pop(primera_llave)

Reitero que, en la práctica, esto lo ejecuta una función que baja la receta de una base de datos y la convierte en el diccionario receta. La función de peso total de la receta la estoy dejando porque aunque no sirva para esta receta, van a haber casos en que la receta es porcentual y por tanto hay que dar al programa un peso máximo que luego hay que dividir según las proporciones de la receta. Pero aún no llego a eso. Tengo que resolver esto primero
Ahora dejo la parte que simula el caso de la balanza, es lo más cercano que se me ocurrió para reproducir el caso, dejé comentarios para más o menos explicar lo que está pasando:
#ejecución de la clase
#en la representación, pedido es automático, en la realidad, una función lo activa 
#descarga la receta de la base de datos y activa el pedido
pedido=Pedido(sumar_peso_receta(receta))


bool(receta)


#Esto es más o menos una representación de lo que pasa en la realidad.
#en tanto se reciba la señal del indicador de la balanza y el diccionario(receta) tenga información, 
#el bucle se sigue ejecuntando
while bool(receta)==True:
        
    balanza=float(input('cuanto marca la balanza?: '))
    p_receta=float(pedido.alcualizar_primer_ingrediente(receta))

    pedido.pesar_ingrediente(balanza, p_receta)

else:
    print('Pesaje completado')

Agrego que al ejecutar la clase pedido=Pedido(), la declaro también como una variable global, pues en el código fuente, el módulo de recepción de la señal del indicador (lo que aquí es el ciclo while bool(receta)) está mucho más arriba en el código y no reconocía el llamado de la clase.
El problema sigue siendo que, tras pesar el segundo ingrediente, el peso acumulado se convierte en 4.0 en lugar se ser: 2.0 (el acumulado del ingrediente pasado)+0.2 (el ingrediente actual)

El algoritmo de esa función está extraño: primero peso_receta += peso_acumulado y luego al final peso_acumulado += peso_receta. Con el uso (probablemente innecesario) de variables globales, la ejecución de esa función varias veces por supuesto que va a duplicar el valor de la variable global por cada llamada. Debido a que empieza con 0.0, el efecto se ve en la iteración 3. Mencionas bucles pero aquí no se ve ningún for o while, por lo que se necesita más información para analizar el problema.

Me suena que en la última línea debería ser = en vez de +=

Como comenta aeportugal,  peso_acumulado+=float(peso_receta) no tiene sentido porque peso_receta en este punto ya tiene sumado el peso acumulado al hacer peso_receta+=float(peso_acumulado) antes del if. Si haces peso_acumulado+=float(peso_receta) es como si al incio de la función hicieras peso_acumulado = peso acumulado + peso_acumulado + peso_receta, lo que es 0  + 0 + 0.2 = 2 en la primera llamada, 2  + 2 +  0.2  = 4.2 en la segunda y 4.2  + 4.2  + 0.1 =  8.5 en la tercera.

@FJSevilla Hermano, actualicé el código siguiendo la guía de la respuesta que dejó moe, pero sigo teniendo problemas. Si pudiera ver que estoy haciendo mal te lo agradecería

@FJSevilla Lo corregí, pero ahora al llamar la función para definir el peso del ingrediente, me arroja:    self.peso_ingrediente=self.peso_acumulado+peso_ingrediente                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict' 

Porque cuando llamas a pedido.pesar_ingrediente(balanza, receta)  receta es un diccionario, deberia ser en todo caso pedido.pesar_ingrediente(balanza, breceta). Tienes otros problemas, por ejemplo self.peso_ingrediente=self.peso_acumulado+peso_ingrediente  está mal, el identificador peso_ingrediente es el método de instancia cuando haces eso no volverás a poderlo llamar ya que pedido.peso_ingrediente ya no será un metodo sino un atributo de instancia, un float, resultado de self.peso_acumulado+peso_ingrediente y tendrás un TypeError por intentar llamar a un float.

Me pondré a ello, no me había dado cuenta de que escribí mal la variable

Carlos sería bueno que explicaras detalladamente que esperas que haga la app paso a paso y mejor aún con un ejemplo. Intentar deducir que resultado esperas a través de código con problemas solo va a generar respuestas parciales y basadas en interpetaciones ¿La receta son pesos absolutos o proporciones? Si es lo segundo, ¿la idea sería dar el peso total del pedido e ir calculando los pesos de cada ingrediente en base a las proporciones y validar el pesaje del usuario en base al margen de error?

@FJSevilla Son ambos, absolutos y proporcionales. El programa descarga la receta de una base de datos, dónde cada ingrediente tiene un peso en específico (en el caso a tratar es absoluto). Necesito que cuando la balanza llegue al peso del primer ingrediente, salte al siguiente ingrediente del diccionaro (por eso sumo el peso acumulado, porque para el compuesto 2, es el peso de la receta mas lo que lleva la balanza) y así hasta iterar todo el diccionario y finalizar la receta. No sé si me estoy explicando bien

De todas formas, lo voy a actualizar más tarde, explicando todo el problema

@FJSevilla Hermano, sigo con mismo problema. Pero hice lo que me dijiste y reescribí toda la pregunta y su planteamiento, siguiendo paso a paso lo que intenta hacer mi código. Sé que me han ayudado mucho, pero sigo sin poder hacerlo funcionar. Y estoy atrasado con la entrega... Muchas gracias de antemano

Al cambiar tu pregunta has invalidado las respuestas previas.

debo decir que es difícil entender que es lo que debe hacer el código, te dejo una aproximación, en base a lo que creo haber entendido.
receta = { 'maiz':2.0, 'proteinas':0.2, 'vacuna':0.2, 'hierro': 0.1 }

def sumar_peso_receta( receta ):
    peso = 0.00
    pesosIngredientes = []
    balanza = Balanza()
    for i in receta.keys():
        print( i )
        pesoIngrediente = balanza.preparar( i, receta[ i ] )
        pesosIngredientes.append( pesoIngrediente )
        print( pesoIngrediente )
        print( pesosIngredientes )
        peso += pesoIngrediente
        print( peso )
    print( round( float( peso), 3 ))
    return round( float( peso ), 3 )

class Balanza:
    cantidad = 0
    ingrediente = ""
    
    def preparar( self, ingrediente, peso ): 
        self.cantidad = 0
        self.ingrediente = ingrediente
        while self.cantidad < peso:
            self.agregar()
            print( f"  ->  {self.cantidad}" )
        
        print( 'Pesaje completado' )
        return self.cantidad
            
    def agregar( self ):
        self.cantidad += 0.1

La clase Balanza, simula la llegada de la orden, con el tipo de ingrediente y la cantidad del mismo, en cada iteración, va agregando peso hasta alcanzar el valor deseado, que entonces devuelve.
Si estoy en el camino correcto, pon en los comentarios que estaría faltando.
